# OpenID Connect SSO Integration with IP based URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am pretty new to SSO integration. I need to understand some basic things to do my SSO integration task in my org. The requirement is, I have .NET application with form based authentication.

Now my org wanted to do the SSO integration. My .NET application does not have any domain name. Currently it is IP based (http://11.22.33.44). And my org stated that only openid connect to be done. Is it possible to do SSO integration with IP based URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using IdentityServer 3 which is an implementation of OpenID Connect. In IdentityServer you are free to assign any valid url: either with host names or ip addresses as redirect_uri. The only requirement is, that uri, provided by application for redirection and uri, configured on IdentityServer for that particular application must match.